# Can't install newer (latest) version of opencv-contrib-python in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi, opencv-contrib

I have been trying to install the latest version of "opencv-contrib-python" package in the new Raspberry Pi (RPi 4). At the time of this writing, the latest version is 4.2.0.34. When I do not specify the version with command *pip install opencv-contrib-python*, it installs an earlier version (4.1.1.26). When I specify the latest version with command *pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34*, it throws an error as follows 
*ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34*.

I tried to look at the official pip webpage (https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/), they have this problem under FAQs, where they recommend upgrading **pip** and installing **wheel**. I have tried these long before.

I really appreciate it if anyone can comment who might have come across this problem.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python3.7

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, here is no solution to this problem. The latest version (4.2.0.34) available in pypi.org cannot be installed on the Raspberry Pi. The wheels for Raspberry Pi (ARM processors) are available at https://www.piwheels.org. However, piwheels website has not yet got the latest version, rather the latest successful build version at this website is 4.1.1.26. Unless piwheels website immediately tracks its parent pypi.org, it would not be possible to install latest version of the package on the Raspberry Pi. 
I guess the alternative would be to build the opencv-contrib-python from the source.